# PySpark How to get last day of quarter from string YYYY/QQ

Tags: date, pyspark

I need to get last day of quarter from string like this **2022/4** where **2022** is year and **4** is quarter. My result is this code:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as fun

fun.date_add(fun.date_trunc('quarter', fun.add_months(fun.to_date(fun.concat_ws(
    "-",
    fun.substring(col("period2"), 0, 4),
    fun.substring(col("period2"), -1, 1),
    lit(1)
)), 3)), -1)
```

But I think my code isn`t the best way to find last day of quarter. I`m wondering if there is another solution of my task?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df = df.withColumn(
    'last_day',
    fun.last_day(fun.concat(fun.substring_index('period2', '/', 1), fun.lit('-'), fun.substring_index('period2', '/', -1).cast('int') * 3))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the year-quarter to the date and find the last day by + a month - a day.

```
data = ['2022/4']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, StringType())

df.withColumn('split', f.split('value', '/')) \
  .withColumn('year', f.col('split')[0]) \
  .withColumn('quarter', f.col('split')[1]) \
  .withColumn('date', f.to_date(f.concat(f.col('year'), f.lit('-'), (f.col('quarter') * 3).cast('int')), 'y-M')) \
  .withColumn('last_day', f.expr('date + interval 1 month - interval 1 day')) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+------+---------+----+-------+----------+----------+
|value |split    |year|quarter|date      |last_day  |
+------+---------+----+-------+----------+----------+
|2022/4|[2022, 4]|2022|4      |2022-12-01|2022-12-31|
+------+---------+----+-------+----------+----------+
```